# React.FC call with multiple parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to call the function with three parameter but its not working.

Here is the `React.FC`:

```
const FormStructure: React.FC<{ record: ModelClass, question: Array<ModelClass>, dropdownItems: Array<ModelTypeClass> }> = ({
    record, question, dropdownItems,
}) => {
...
}
```

and this is the function call:

```
return (
   <Modal
      visible={this.state.modalVisible}
      onCancel={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: false })}
   >
      {FormStructure(record, this.state.question, this.state.dropdownItems)}
   </Modal>
)
```

Following Error Message:
*"Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since FormStructure is a component, you shouldn't be calling it as a function. You should instead create a JSX element:

```
<Modal
  visible={this.state.modalVisible}
  onCancel={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: false })}
>
  <FormStructure 
    record={record}
    question={this.state.question}
    dropdownItems={this.state.dropdownItems}
  </FormStructure>
</Modal>
```

If, hypothetically, you wanted to call it as a function (again, you shouldn't do that since this is a component), the way to conform to the type definition is to pass in an object with three properties:

```
FormStructure({ 
  record: record,
  question: this.state.question,
  dropdownItems: this.state.dropdownItems,
});
```

Comment: When is it advisable to use the function syntax then?

Comment: If it's a component, pretty much never.

Answer (score 1):

`FormStructure` is a Functional Component, so you better render it with the following syntax (JSX):

```
return (
  <Modal
    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
    onCancel={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: false })}
  >
    <FormStructure record={record} question={this.state.question} dropdownItems={this.state.dropdownItems)} />
  </Modal>
)
```